# I want to know, how to select date in datepicker by Robot Framework

Tags: angularjs, robotframework, robotframework-ide

I want to know , How to select date in datepicker by Robotframwork . If someone have any idea it's will be great to help

[image: Datepicker Visual]
[image: Date Picker Code]

I'm new robotframework

Link to the HTML source code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WFhwU3bh1-zaddzw01le6ASfY0gT5kgt/view

Comment: Can you add example HTML code of the date functionality you want to automate. Without it we won't be able to help you. If you have any Robot Script your working on, please add that as well. You can edit your question through the edit link under the tags.

Comment: i update to picture in  question

Comment: Let me start with that Screen Shots of code are frowned upon at [so]. When they are taken of code, they prevent us from copy-and-pasting and generally will prevent people from helping. For this reason I'd like to ask you to copy the complete code for the date picker until the first item in the first row (28). As I suspect that this is an Angular application. Have you looked at the specific Angular test libraries or functionality?

Comment: ah  Do you want all code html right?

Comment: Not the entire Page, just the section for the date picker.

Comment: i add link  html , it's in googledrive

Comment: Have you tried the [AngularJSlibrary](https://github.com/Selenium2Library/robotframework-angularjs). It seems to me to be the better apporach to treating everything as regular HTML.